# Javascript to find content

Tags: javascript

Hi I am using code below, but getting 'undefined' as a result. How to fix this?
I am not sure how to call for a class within a class.

```js
function myFunction() {    
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker").innerHTML; 
}
```

```html
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product</span>

<p>Click the button to change the text in "mydiv".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="mydiv">***</p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker")[0]`. Get elementS!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: As `getElementS` states, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like HTMLCollection.

So inorder to access the first element (your class `inline-keyword-marker`), you need to add `[0]` to your method like this:

`document.getElementsByClassName('inline-keyword-marker')[0]`

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker")[0].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product</span>

<p>Click the button to change the text in "mydiv".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="mydiv">***</p>
```

You might also to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method). It explains your issue more detailed than I did.

---

To handle all your classes, you can use this method:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('inline-keyword-marker'); // Get all elements
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv'); // Get the div for the result

  myDiv.innerHTML = ""; // At first, we clear the result div; not neccessary, just for the optic
  
  // Because we got a HTMLCollection back, we need to loop through it
  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    myDiv.innerHTML += classes[i].innerHTML + "<br>"; // With [i] we access every element -> at first the first one, then the second on and so on
    // I also added a <br> tag, so the results get append beneath each other, not next to each other
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product1</span>
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product2</span>
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product3</span>
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product4</span>
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product5</span>

<p>Click the button to change the text in "mydiv".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="mydiv">***</p>
```

Comment: The answer is already given in the comment.So why post it again?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt True, but I wanted to explain the solution in a more detailed way.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for a answer - however, I just realised that class "inline-keyword-marker" occurs multiple times. How to I modify the code to create a list of contents of all occurrences in a page?

Comment: @VijaysinhPatil So you want to display the `innerHTML` of every class `inline-keyword-marker` on your page?

Comment: @CodeF0x, yes. There are several of these classes and I want to extract their content into a list.

Comment: @VijaysinhPatil Please take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem :

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array and not a single value so in order to select one you can do this `[i]` where is the index of the elements so :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker")
```

becomes :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker")[0]
```

and selects the first element with class `inline-keyword-marker`

So total JavaScript becomes  :

```js
myFunction = () => {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker")[0].innerHTML; 
}
```

## Shorter :

```js
myFunction = () => (d=document).getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = d.getElementsByClassName("inline-keyword-marker")[0].innerHTML
```

```html
<span class="inline-keyword-marker valid">Product</span>

<p>Click the button to change the text in "mydiv".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="mydiv">***</p>
```